# Form submission redirect to white page

Tags: 6, forms

I've created a simple form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function test_menu() {
    $items['admin/config/test'] = array(
        'title' => 'Test form submission',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('test_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function test_form($form) {
    $form['test_text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Test text')
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save')
    );

    return $form;
}

function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));
}
```

On submission, I see a white page. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please don't just dump code on us. Describe what you meant, what have you tried, what URL this form is under, to what URL user is redirected, and so on. In other words, at least try to debug it yourself. And if you did, *show it* in your question.

Comment: You should enable error logging to get an idea of what's wrong happened https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468

Answer (score 2):

This is Drupal 6, so

```
function test_form($form) {
```

Needs to be

```
function test_form(&$form_state) {
```

Currently you're returning a form that has the initial form state data attached to it, which Drupal is probably objecting to on submission.